# How to capture Embedded-debezium database connection failures with java?

Tags: debezium

In my embedded debezium based CDC application, I want to capture the database connection failures to retry the connection automatically.

Is there a way to capture that the database connection is failed in my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the `EmbeddedEngine` using a `CompletionCallback`.

```
EmbeddedEngine.CompletionCallback completionCallback = (success, message, error) -> {
    //Handle the error.
};
EmbeddedEngine engine = EmbeddedEngine.create()
                        .using(completionCallback)
                        ...
                        .build();
```